# Uncaught syntax error: Adding <li> elements to an <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I keep getting an `uncaught syntex error` which I know usually means your code has a missing closing something. I keep failing to see what it is that I am missing.

The idea of the function is that it extracts the a links ID and Text content and add's it to an un-ordered list.

The links have a class of 'ingredient_add' and the unordered list has an ID of 'ingredientsAdded'.

I can't see what I've missed here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ingredient_add').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = this.id;
        var value = this.text();
        $('#ingredientsAdded').append("<li id='"+id+"'>"+value+"</li>");
    }); //end add to list
}); // end document ready()
```

Comment: Indenting would be nice.

Comment: This does not give a syntax error. Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I am 100% certain that that isn't the *actual* error. Could you share what the actual error is? (One obvious mistake is that your function doesn't receive the `event` parameter.)

Comment: `$('.ingredient_add').click(function(){`

Where is event here? Try `$('.ingredient_add').click(function(event){`

Comment: Also, unlike jQuery collections, `Element`s don't have `.text()` methods. `value` should either be assigned to `$(this).text();` or `this.textContent;`. In a few cases, such as `<option>`s, `this.text` (property, not method) may be a 3rd option.

Comment: My Error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello your problem was just a simple mistake.

```
var value = $(this).text();
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/pFLXf/1/

I updated your code. Watch out not to use the same id more than once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 0;
$('.ingredient_add').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var id = this.id;
var value = $(this).text();
$('#ingredientsAdded').append('<li id="'+id+counter+'">'+value+'</li>');
counter+=1;
}); //end add to list

}); // end document ready()
```

Comment: This now works with a test link that I have created, the problem Ii have is that the links are dynamically generated from an Ajax request connecting to database. It now throws an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. The only difference between the test link and the dynamic links is that they are wrapped in a `<span>`. Any idea why they wouldn't work?

Comment: That error usually means you are missing a '(' ')' '{' '}' somewhere. I would have to see your JS code to be sure.

Comment: I've messed around with it, it has nothing to do with the `<span>` element. This element is what the dynamic links are loaded into. The problem I believe is that it is dynamic content. As the links are loaded in after the rest of the document the JS doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Make me a jsfiddle with your modifcations, otherwise I won't be able to help you much more. And you're right, it has nothing to do with <span> (imo). That is a typical JS syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks good. You do need to pass in the event to the function though.

```
$('.ingredient_add').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
```

Check out Jonathan Lonowskis comment on your .text().

Answer (score 1):

The error you should be getting is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
$('.ingredient_add').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();   <-- what is event?
```

should be

```
$('.ingredient_add').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

if you are still getting that error, there is something else going on that is not in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You missed an argument in click handler function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.ingredient_add').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var id = this.id;
var value = this.text();
$('#ingredientsAdded').append("<li id='"+id+"'>"+value+"</li>");

}); //end add to list

}); // end document ready()
```